# Make all divs in a row the size of tallest one

Tags: html, css

I have a div container, with child divs.

What I am trying to do is make all in a divs in a row size to the height of the tallest one.
If clear: both is used, any divs on the next row should all be height of the tallest in that row as well.

I can add classes to the html but i can't change the structure, eg nest more divs and rows e.t.c. so solution must be css based

I have tried using display: table, and display: table-cell.. no luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/6gv5sgq1/

HTML

```
<div id=container>
    <div>
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
    </div>
    <div>
    a<br>a
    </div>
    <div class=newline>
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
    </div>
    <div>
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
}

#container div {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.newline {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use jQuery or javascript along with this.

Comment: You van probably accomplish this with flexbox: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Answer (score 1):

You aren't far off with your current code.

Separate rows with a `display: table-row`

Then remove `float: left` from your `table-cell`s

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gv5sgq1/4/)

```css
#container {
     display: table;
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 500px;
    }
    
    #container .tr {
        display: table-row;
    }
    
    #container .tr >div {
        border-right: 2px solid red;
        background: #f7f7f7;
     display: table-cell;
     margin: 2px;
     width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div id=container>
       <div class="tr">
      <div>
          a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
      </div>
      <div>
          a<br>a
      </div>
       </div>
        <div class=tr>
      <div>
                a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
            </div>
      <div>
          a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```